# Dynamic Filter of Iframe with Two Input Fields

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to make a dynamic filter on one iframe with two input boxes.  Let's call the input boxes "Box 1" and "Box 2".  When both boxes are not populated, I would like the iframe to display all of the information.  When Box A is populated, I want it to display information on Box A.  When Box B is populated as well, I would like both the filters to apply.  When only Box B is populated, I would like the iframe to only display Box B's input.

One limitation I have is the changing nature of having one of the input boxes blank. I am limited to assigning a number to the input on the URL (e.g. - col1, op1, val1). If the "salModBox" is blank for instance, it needs to be dynamic enough to assign "serNumPrefBox" with col1, op1, val1). If both are populated, it would need to be col1, op1, val1 for "salModBox" and col2, op2, val2 for "serNumPrefBox". If neither are populated, well, it doesn't need to have col1 or 2 for that matter.

Expected output of the URL would ultimately look like this if both are populated:

https://example.com/#/embed/viz/longID/?col1=Variable%20Number%20One&op1=EQ&val1="+salesMod+"&col2=Variable%20Number%20Two&op2=EQ&val2="+serNoPre+"#/moreinfo/anotherID

Expected output of the URL with one variable populated:

https://example.com/#/embed/viz/longID/?col1=Variable%20Number%20One&op1=EQ&val1="+salesMod (or serNoPre) +"#/moreinfo/anotherID

With both of them blank, it would simply be the original URL source link.  This would be a wide open search.  A user isn't technically limited to values they can put in either input box.

```js
function salModSnpFilter() {
   var salModInput = document.getElementById('salModBox').value;
   var serNumPrefInput = document.getElementById('serNumPrefBox').value;
   var smSnp = '';
   if (salModInput = ' ' and serNumPrefInput = ' ') {"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IFrame"
   } else if (salModInput = ' ' and serNumPrefInput != ' ') {"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IFrame" + serNumPrefInput
      } else if (serNumPrefInput = ' ' and salModInput != ' ') {"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IFrame" + salModInput
      } else if (salModInput != ' ' and serNumPrefInput != ' ' {"chttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IFrame"+salModInput+serNumPrefInput
   } else {"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IFrame"
   }

    var salModString = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IFrame" + salModInput";
    var serNumPrefString = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IFrame" + serNumPrefInput";
    var bothString = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IFrame" + serNumPrefInput + salModInput";

 document.getElementById('SM_SNPiFrame').src = salModString;
 document.getElementById('SM_SNPiFrame').src = serNumPrefString;
  document.getElementById('SM_SNPiFrame').src = bothString;
  
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input name="textfield" type="text" class="guidedQueryEntry" placeholder="Box A" name="Box A" id="salModBox">
</div>
<div>
  <input name="textfield" type="text" class="guidedQueryEntry" placeholder="Box B" name = "Box B" id="serNumPrefBox">
</div>
<div>
  <iframe src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IFrame"
    width="100%" height="600" style="border-color:#FFCD11" id="SM_SNPiFrame" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

I ultimately used this code and it worked:

```
    function filterSelection() {
        var smBoxValue = document.getElementById("salModBox").value;
        var snpBoxValue = document.getElementById("serNumPrefBox").value;
        if (smBoxValue != "" && snpBoxValue != "") {var combinedModString = 
        "https://example.com/col1=Serial%20Number%20Prefix&op1=EQ&val1=" + 
         snpBoxValue +"&col2=Sales%20Model%20BOM%20EDS&op2=EQ&val2=" + 
         smBoxValue";
         document.getElementById('SM_SNPiFrame').src = combinedModString;
         }
         else if (smBoxValue == "" && snpBoxValue != "") {var snpModString = 
         "https://example.com/#/col1=Serial%20Number%20Prefix&op1=EQ&val1=" 
         + snpBoxValue;
         document.getElementById('SM_SNPiFrame').src = snpModString;
         }
         else if (smBoxValue != "" && snpBoxValue == "") {var salModString = 
         "https://example/col1=Sales%20Model%20BOM%20EDS&op1=EQ&val1=" + 
         smBoxValue;
         document.getElementById('SM_SNPiFrame').src = salModString;
         }
         else {document.getElementById('SM_SNPiFrame').src = 
         "https://example.com/";
         }  
         }
```

Comment: What would your iframe url look like? (Expected outputs examples) Will it always be only two input boxes? Does it have only certain allowed values for one (or both) inputs? If you can edit your question with those details it will be really helpful to give you the fix you need.

Comment: Added more detail.

Comment: You still haven't provided which input is related to which query in the url, I still not understand what your issue is right now..

Comment: @k3llydev - I was able to use the modified code and it worked.  Not sure if this is the most efficient code or not.

Comment: Oh, alrtight.. If my answer helped you feel free to upvote and accept it so you question is marked as "answered".

Comment: @k3llydev - Upvoted and accepted the answer.  It did help me come to my conclusion.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems a bit complex than what your issue is, I'll explain to you how to correct this and use some good practices in JavaScript.

Since you need to handle the values inside the input tags and use them into the `iFrame` tag, we will do the following:

### Global elements first.

Since we will probably need to define only once which DOM element is the `iFrame` tag and which ones are the `input` tags, lets have them at the very beginning:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('SM_SNPiFrame'),
    elements = [
        document.getElementById('salModBox'),
        document.getElementById('serNumPrefBox')
    ],
    strings = [];
```

Also, we define a `strings` variable that will help us store the input values in the same index as `elements` array.

### Set event listeners for every element.

After defining which elements we want to use, now we should handle the change of its value. The most fast-looking effect is to use `keyup` event, this will pass the value everytime that the user types:

```
elements.forEach((e,index)=>{
    e.addEventListener("keyup",event=>{
    strings[index] = event.target.value;
    salModSnpFilter();
  });
});
```

In this event listener, you need to setup what will happen every time this event is fired. I just did a simple function to store the new value into the same index but in different array (strings array).

And after that done, call the function that will update the `iFrame` tag.

### Keep your code simple and functional.

The function `salModSnpFilter()` doesn't need a lot of if statements and the same string appearing multiple times to handle the new source of the iFrame. Lets keep code simple:

```
const salModSnpFilter = () => {
    let source = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IFrame",
        finalString = "/"; //You can set it to empty: "" if you dont want slashes.
    strings.forEach(string => {
        if (string !== "") {
            finalString += string; //You can add a slash with  by adding: + "/" between the s and the semicolon.
        }
    });
    iframe.src = source + finalString;
};
```

We define the base URL in a variable at the top and a variable that will hold the string that we will append to the base source.

We iterate over the `strings` array and add this string to `finalString` array in the same order of the inputs.

After this, the only thing left to do is to set the source of the `iFrame` tag.

### Final code:

```js
var iframe = document.getElementById('SM_SNPiFrame'),
  elements = [
      document.getElementById('salModBox'),
      document.getElementById('serNumPrefBox')
    ],
    strings = [];

elements.forEach((e,index)=>{
 e.addEventListener("keyup",event=>{
   strings[index] = event.target.value;
    salModSnpFilter();
  });
});

const salModSnpFilter = () =>{
  let source = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IFrame",
    finalString = "/";//You can set it to empty: "" if you dont want slashes.
  strings.forEach(string=>{
   if(string !== ""){
     finalString += string; //You can add a slash with  by adding: + "/" between the s and the semicolon.
    }
  });
 iframe.src = source + finalString;
};
```

```html
<div>
    <input name="textfield" type="text" class="guidedQueryEntry" placeholder="Box A" name="Box A" id="salModBox">
</div>
<div>
    <input name="textfield" type="text" class="guidedQueryEntry" placeholder="Box B" name="Box B" id="serNumPrefBox">
</div>
<div>
    <iframe src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IFrame" width="100%" height="600" style="border-color:#FFCD11" id="SM_SNPiFrame" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

***Note:*** The order of the strings and how they are used on the `iFrame` are the same as the order you added the inputs to the `elements` array. This means, inputA value will always go before inputB value. Unless you change the order in the `elements` array.

Comment: This is really useful and appreciate you taking the time to explain it to me in detail.  One thing I left out is the changing nature of having one of the input boxes blank.  I am limited to assigning a number to the input on the URL (e.g. - col1, op1, val1).  If the "salModBox" is blank for instance, it needs to be dynamic enough to assign "serNumPrefBox" with col1, op1, val1).  If both are populated, it would need to be col1, op1, val1 for "salModBox" and col2, op2, val2 for "serNumPrefBox".  If neither are populated, well, it doesn't need to have col1 or 2 for that matter.

Comment: @jvelt17 You can still edit your question and provide what you didn't mention so I can give the respective adjustments to my answer. Just make sure to leave a comment here when you did so I get notified:)

Comment: Sounds great.  I was able to modify my question with this information.  Please feel free to ask for clarification.  I tried a few different things without any luck.  I was able to get the input for Box A working appropriately but I couldn't figure out how to get A and B working together or just B for that matter due to the changing values based on an input being blank or not.

Comment: Also, this may help:  The way I handled it before limited me to entering both values in this manner:  var urlstring7_2 = "https://example.com/#/embed/viz/longID/?col1=Variable%20Number%20One&op1=EQ&val1="+snp+"&col2=Variable%20Number%20Two&op2=EQ&val2="+part+"#/moreinfo/anotherID";